# delete rows if duplicate exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete duplicate rows in my table. It should keep the first one, or the one on top and if there is any other duplicates it should be deleted.

[image]

As the image shows there is two 12 and two 13. So keep the first 12 in the database and if there is any other delete them same goes for 13 or any ID.

My Idea:

```
DELETE from [Table]
WHERE [ID]
HAVING COUNT(TABLE.ID) > 1;
```

Comment: How do you know what row comes before another row? You need a column to order your rows by.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I was thinking about that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.

Something like

```
;WITH DeleteRows AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RowID
    FROM    [Table]
)
DELETE from DeleteRows
WHERE RowID > 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/595e6/4)

Comment: Nice, let me try that

Comment: `ROWNUMBER' is not a recognized built-in function name` on that

Comment: I have corrected my typo. Please have a look again, or at the SQL Fiddle DEMO.